# Cannot Find A Group Policy That I'd Like To Disable

Tags: windows, active-directory, group-policy

There's an Active Directory group policy specific to Google Chrome in place to enforce:

- startup URLs
- blocking auto-updating (locking to a particular version)

This policy writes entries to

- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Google`
- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google`

The AD policy is defined for :

- `User Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Google\Google Chrome\Startup Pages`

As an administrator on a machine on the domain with this group policy applied, how can I remove or work around that applied group policy?

Using `gpedit.msc` with run-as Administrator, I cannot see/find the particular policy that I'd like to override. **How** can I find this group policy object?

[image]

Comment: If you are not an `Administrator` of the domain you can't.  Just because you have a local Administrator account does not mean you have `Administrator` permissions.  The domain permissions will always override the local permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need the Google Chrome AD template files to add those policies to your console.

> For Windows, there are two types of policy templates available, an ADM and an ADMX template. You'll want to verify which template type you can use on your network. These templates show which registry keys you can set to configure Chrome, and what the acceptable values are. Chrome looks at the values set in these registry keys to determine how to act.

You can get them from Google [here](http://dl.google.com/dl/edgedl/chrome/policy/policy_templates.zip).
[Source/Additional Info](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/187202?hl=en)

Be aware that if you're not a Domain Admin, and you're not changing the Domain's GP, then anything you chance will just reset at the next GP refresh.

Also be aware that circumventing company policies are a good way to get fired, so working with the domain admin's would be more preferable :)